# AngularJS - Display value of key that is a number

Tags: html, angularjs

I have checked a couple previously asked questions but could not find the answer I am looking for. I am working on a table which uses an ng-repeat to go through an array of in my case tasks. The repeat looks as follows:

```
ng-repeat="task in tasks.data"
```

My task object which looks as follows, it consists of regular values and a custom_fields object:

```
task {
    x : y,
    a : b,
    c : d,
    custom_fields {
       89829 : value
    }
}
```

When I try to display the value of the key using:

```
task.custom_fields.89829
```

it returns a Syntax Error because of the key being an unexpected token. When I rename it to something different such as:

```
task.custom_fields.test
```

it does display properly.

My question is, is it possible to display values of a key that is a number?

Comment: `task.custom_fields[89829]`

Comment: @charliebrownie I just tried this, it does not display any value unfortunately
EDIT: I had changed the value before, my apologies. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a string as the index. `task.custom_fields["89829"]`. Javascript objects are basically just big dictionaries, you can access any property using the property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the property within square brackets

```
task.custom_fields['89829']
```

And you json is also invalid. modify like this

```
var task = {
    x : y,
    a : b,
    c : d,
    custom_fields: {
       89829 : value
    }
}
```

Demo

```js
var task =  {
    x : 1,
    a : 2,
    c : 3,
    custom_fields : {
       89829 : 123
    }
}

console.log(task.custom_fields['89829'])
```

Comment: I thank you kindly, this works! Also my JSON is not the actual JSON I displayed on the question, it was just my example to make the question more clear :).

Comment: @Lesleyvdp  no problem :D

Comment: @Lesleyvdp make sure to check it as answer if this helped :D